# Populating a large SQLite database with values derived from a custom script

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a database in SQLite Studio with a table named "LOCATIONS". This table has the following columns:

- location_id (pk)
- location_x
- location_y

I wish to populate this database with an id and location of each pixel in a 2000x1000 matrix (1,0,0 ; 2,0,1 ; 3,0,2 ; ... 2000000,1999,999).

First I ran the following in Java and saved the output to a .txt:

```
public class matrix {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int c = 1;
    for (int x = 0; x < 2000; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < 1000; y++) {
        System.out.print("('" +c+ "','" +x+ "','" +y+ "')\n");
        c++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I (pardon my lack of programming expertise here) tried copying the 2M lines directly into an insert statement in SQLStudio's SQL Editor, but my computer can't handle it and crashes the program everytime.

What would be an optimal solution to my problem?

Comment: Forget java and use just SQL from SQLite command line.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you to make `location_id (pk)` as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` field then instead of generating all values of rows use a CTE like this:

```
with recursive x(i) as(
    select 1
    union all
    select i+1
    from x
    where i<2000
), y(i) as(
    select 1
    union all
    select i+1
    from y
    where i<1000
), t as (
  select x.i x, y.i y
  from x
  cross join y
)
insert into LOCATIONS (location_id, location_x,location_y)
select null, x, y
from t
order by x, y;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9eecb7/5689)

Comment: Thought better using computed id to ensure correct id, but this solution is much faster.